# SSRS Goup header evaluates expression only once

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2016

I have a SSRS 2016 report which has two group headers.  I want one group header to show up on the first page of each group item and then the other header to be visible for the following pages.

I have tried many solutions for instance setting a page number variable in the header and then reading that value in the header but it doesn't work.

It seems that the logic in the group header is only evaluated at the start of every group.

Do you know if that is correct or is there a way to display a different header for a group on each page.

Answer (score 0):

In the Group Panel, right click the parent group, go to Group Properties, then Page Breaks and here you go!